# Error running Apache Mahout K-Means

Tags: hadoop, k-means, mahout

I am trying to execute Apache Mahout K-Means algorithm on Apache Hadoop with this dataset [Tennis Major Tournament Match Statistics from UCI Machine Learning Repository], but I have one error when I execute the clusterdump command. I am following the steps on this tutorial [https://imiloainf.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/mahout-kmeans-example/ ]. This is the error:
[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is incorrect.

Fix your command line.

Comment: What is the `-s` parameter?